# Error message: qgis_core.dll missing

Tags: qgis, error, qgis-2.4

I have a fresh install of QGIS 2.4. When trying to open a .shp file I get the error message below.

I've followed their advice and have done several re-installs and also cleared all qgis files from my system (Parallels on Mac OS X 10.6) before those re-installs. I've tried QGIS 2.2 which caused the same problem.

Funnily all worked for a day, the following day and since not anymore...

Has anyone come across this before?

[image: qgis_core]

Comment: Just did a fresh install of 2.10.1 (32 bit) on Windows and it has the same problem when running bin\qgis-bin.exe

Comment: After installation I open it but the response was..I have a missing (qgis.app.dll) so I need to reinstall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also receive the same when opening .shp files directly and selecting qgis-bin as the program to use. But I always load QGIS via the Desktop icon. I'm not exactly sure why but my guess is that the Desktop icon simultaneously runs the following 2 files in order to load QGIS (this is the Target which you can see in the icon's properties):

> "C:\Program Files\QGIS Valmiera\bin\nircmd.exe" exec hide C:\PROGRA~1\QGISVA~1\bin\qgis.bat

My advice is to load QGIS via the Desktop icon (usually has a name like "QGIS Desktop 2.4.0") and then drag/drop your shapefile that way.

**Edit**:

As Steve has already found out, it's possible to drag your shapefile to the "qgis.bat" file which will load QGIS and the shapefile itself.

Comment: Joseph, this works here! I've now also re-mapped .shp files directly to the qgis.bat so that I can click them directly.

Comment: Brilliant! You just taught me something also :)

Comment: Mapping the shapefile to QGIS is awesome.

Comment: @Branco, certainly is buddy! Only been 9 months since I first started using GIS software of any kind (I chose QGIS) and still there's masses of things for me to learn :)

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue recently. None of the answers here worked to me.

When I use QGIS 2.4, I usually work with my laptop plugged in a bigger lcd monitor. Then, I project everything in the second monitor using a hdmi adapater. So, when I turned off the second monitor, QGIS started to show the message 'qgis_core.dll missing'.

To fix, I pressed the key 'Fn + F1' (Dell laptop) and choose the first option to project images only to the first monitor. Than, the QGIS worked again.