# qgis-bin.exe - System Error

Tags: qgis

I'm running QGIS 2.8 Wien on Windows 8.1. I got this error:

> The program can't start because qgis_core.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I got the same error last week, uninstalled and reinstalled QGIS and it worked. But there must be a better way to fix the error than reinstalling QGIS every time it bombs out.

Comment: Does this question help? http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/120346/43

Comment: Are you running qgis.exe or qgis.bat?

Comment: I'm clicking the shortcut that comes with a standard Windows installation of QGIS. The shortcut target is: "C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\bin\nircmd.exe" exec hide C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\bin\qgis.bat

Comment: Does qgis.bat typed manually inside the OSGEO4W shell work?

Comment: Yes, it works - same if I find the qgis.bat file in Windows Explorer and run it.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due to the antivirus software. QGIS works fine at first but this problem arose after a reboot. Try to disable the antivirus software and try again but please do so at your own risk.